# How can I make audio in Safari in iPhone run many audios one by one?

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari, html5-audio

I want to make an application that play 3 consecutive audio file (very small ones, just ~900ms a file), so I wrote these code:

```
function playAudio() {
            audioLinksArray.forEach(function(audioLink, index, array){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    // Find the audio element to play
                    document.getElementById('audio'+index).play();
                }, 900*index);
            });
        }
```

This works fine in desktop browser (I tested on Chrome, Safari, FireFox, Opera). However, when I open Safari on iPhone, it only play the first two audio files and left the last one not played. What is actually happenning and what can I do to fix this?

Comment: Instead of using multiple `Audio`, why don't you just use one and change the url one after another?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I would appreciate your model code

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
audioLinksArray = [0, 1, 2]

function playAudio() {
  var last = audioLinksArray.length - 1;
  var audioElements = new Array(last + 1);
  audioLinksArray.forEach(function(audioLink, index, array){
    var audio = audioElements[index] = document.getElementById('audio' + index);
    if (index === last) return;
    audio.addEventListener('ended', function () {
      audioElements[index + 1].play();
    });
    if (!index) audio.play();
  });
}
```

```html
<audio controls id="audio0" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f6/Voice_of_Zonotrichia_albicollis.ogg"></audio><br>
<audio controls id="audio1" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/68/Turdus_merula_male_song_at_dawn%2820s%29.ogg"></audio><br>
<audio controls id="audio2" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/45/ACDC_-_Back_In_Black-sample.ogg"></audio><br>

<button onclick="playAudio()">Play all</button>
```

Comment: Well somehow in Safari for iPhone, it just plays the first video and left the others unplayed...